# using clickatell on developer central

Tags: clickatell

I have been using the integration from sandbox environment to send free test sms'es and everything is working fine.This is the code that I am using

```
Dictionary<string, string> Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Params.Add("content", Msg);
Params.Add("to", MobileNo);
apikey.response = Api.SendSMS(apikey.api, Params);
```

Now I have a Developer central account and I only changed the API ID and now no SMS'es are going through.I was advised to use the username and password that was given to me - where do I use/put those credentials, please help!

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP send api provides the following uri for sending messages.

https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=your_api_key&to=xxxxxxxxxxx&content=Test+message+text.

This is the implementation I am currently working with. Give it a shot.